# could not find artifact while running maven build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

While building the maven application in jenkins i get the following error

```
    [ERROR] Artifact: com.envoisolutions.sxc:sxc-runtime:jar:0.7.3-osgi has no file.
org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.envoisolutions.sxc:sxc-runtime:jar:0.7.3-osgi in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O-osgi in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
    mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=xpp3 -DartifactId=xpp3_min -Dversion=1.1.3.4.O-osgi -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=xpp3 -DartifactId=xpp3_min -Dversion=1.1.3.4.O-osgi -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]


  xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O-osgi

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
  codehaus-releases (http://repository.codehaus.org/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
  java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
  central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

Is there any way to restrict the search of maven to few repos ?

Answer (score 0):

This artifact seems to be very old.
I found it in this Maven repository :

https://teamcity-systeme.lip6.fr/nexus/content/groups/public

Add this repo to your Maven's pom.

Comment: Validate my answer please :)